# tmux creates persistant, unkillable session

Tags: tmux

I wanted tmux to launch automatically, so I added `[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux` to my `bash.bashrc` file. However, now a session is created that I cannot kill and runs in "windowed" (for lack of a better word) mode.

[image: tmux session in "windowed" mode]

If I run `tmux kill-session -t ##` another "windowed" session is created in its place. I can kill all other sessions fine, but this one stays constant.

I'm accessing the terminal through PuTTY, and there are only two users logged on (myself and the system itself)

How can I kill/prevent the creation of this session?